# Getting an error trying to scrape website using scrapy-playwright

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, playwright

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zk5cS7Ke3eg) to scrape a website

This is my code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_playwright.page import PageMethod

class magicbrick_spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spy'
    
    async def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url = 'https://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom=&proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment,Residential-House,Villa&cityName=Mumbai',
            meta = {
                "playwright" : True,
                "playwright_include_page" : True,
                "playwright_page_methods" : [
                    PageMethod("wait_for_selector", ".mb-srp__card__container:nth-child(10)")
                ]
            },
            errback=self.close_page
        )

    async def parse(self, response):
        page = response.meta['playwright_page']
        for i in range(2, 11):
            containers = 30 * i
            await page.wait_for_selector(f".mb-srp__card__container:nth-child({containers})")
            await page.evaluate("window.scrollBy(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
        html = await page.content()
        await page.close()

        title = html.css(".mb-srp__card--title::text").get()
        yield {"title" : title}

    async def close_page(self, failure):
        page = failure.request.meta['playwright_page']
        await page.close()
```

and this is the error generated on crawling:

```
2022-12-30 12:37:28 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
Unhandled error in Deferred:
2022-12-30 12:37:28 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\amanr\miniconda3\envs\Scraping\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 205, in crawl
    return self._crawl(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\amanr\miniconda3\envs\Scraping\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 209, in _crawl
    d = crawler.crawl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\amanr\miniconda3\envs\Scraping\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1905, in unwindGenerator    
    return _cancellableInlineCallbacks(gen)
  File "C:\Users\amanr\miniconda3\envs\Scraping\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1815, in _cancellableInlineCallbacks
    _inlineCallbacks(None, gen, status)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "C:\Users\amanr\miniconda3\envs\Scraping\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1660, in _inlineCallbacks   
    result = current_context.run(gen.send, result)
  File "C:\Users\amanr\miniconda3\envs\Scraping\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 102, in crawl
    start_requests = iter(self.spider.start_requests())
builtins.TypeError: 'async_generator' object is not iterable

2022-12-30 12:37:28 [twisted] CRITICAL:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\amanr\miniconda3\envs\Scraping\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1660, in _inlineCallbacks   
    result = current_context.run(gen.send, result)
  File "C:\Users\amanr\miniconda3\envs\Scraping\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 102, in crawl
    start_requests = iter(self.spider.start_requests())
TypeError: 'async_generator' object is not iterable
```

I have tried removing the for loop and performed the wait_for_selector and evaluate without it but it is giving the same error.

How do I solve this?

EDIT: Lack of support for windows https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-playwright#lack-of-native-support-for-windows

Answer (score 0):

`scrapy-playwright` doesn't work on Windows OS. However, using the sites search `api` to extract `json` data would be much simpler than using playwright and infinite scroll anyway.

```py
import scrapy

class magicbrick_spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spy'
    def start_requests(self):
        for i in range(50):
            url = f"https://www.magicbricks.com/mbsrp/propertySearch.html?editSearch=Y&category=S&propertyType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&city=4320&page={i}&groupstart={30*i}&offset=0&maxOffset=5&sortBy=premiumRecent&postedSince=-1&pType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&isNRI=Y&multiLang=en"
            yield scrapy.Request(url)

    def parse(self, response):
        for result in response.json().get('resultList'):
            item = {}
            for k,v in {"title":"propertyTitle", "url":"url",
                        "floors":"floorNo", "price":"price",
                        "description":"seoDesc", "id":"id",
                        "bath":"bathD", "beds":"bedroomD",
                        "city":"ctName"}.items():
                item.setdefault(k, result.get(v, None))
            yield item
```

partial output:

```bash
{'title': '1BHK Multistorey Apartment for Resale in Keshav Srishti at Bhandup West', 'url': '1-BHK-600-Sq-ft-Multistorey-Apartment-FOR-Sale-Bhandup-West-in-Mumbai&id=4d423535393038343339', 'floors': '2', 'price': 10100000, 'description':
 'This gorgeous 1 BHK Flat is available for sale in Bhandup West, Mumbai. This flat is placed in a marvellous location within the Keshav Srishti complex. This flat for resale has a desirable location. The  ready to move flat  in the prim
e area of Bhandup West is available at a reasonable price of INR 1.01 Cr. The flat is available in unfurnished condition. Some of the landmarks in the vicinity include bhandup station less than 500 meters.', 'id': '55908439', 'bath': '2'
, 'beds': '1', 'city': 'Mumbai'}
2022-12-31 13:45:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.magicbricks.com/mbsrp/propertySearch.html?editSearch=Y&category=S&propertyType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&city=4320&page=29&groupstart=870&offset=0&m
axOffset=5&sortBy=premiumRecent&postedSince=-1&pType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&isNRI=Y&multiLang=en>
{'title': '2BHK Multistorey Apartment for Resale in La Bellezza at Borivali East', 'url': '2-BHK-915-Sq-ft-Multistorey-Apartment-FOR-Sale-Borivali-East-in-Mumbai&id=4d423632343339313835', 'floors': '6', 'price': 11100000, 'description':
"Borivali East, Mumbai has an attractive 2 BHK Flat for sale. Strategically situated in the La Bellezza site, it is placed at a prime location. This premium flat is available for resale at an unbelievable price, so, grab it before it's g
one! This ready to move property in Borivali East is readily available within an affordable cost of  INR 1.11 Cr. The flat is sold in unfurnished condition.", 'id': '62439185', 'bath': '2', 'beds': '2', 'city': 'Mumbai'}
2022-12-31 13:45:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.magicbricks.com/mbsrp/propertySearch.html?editSearch=Y&category=S&propertyType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&city=4320&page=29&groupstart=870&offset=0&m
axOffset=5&sortBy=premiumRecent&postedSince=-1&pType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&isNRI=Y&multiLang=en>
{'title': '2BHK Multistorey Apartment for Resale in Vivek Apartments at Santacruz West', 'url': '2-BHK-575-Sq-ft-Multistorey-Apartment-FOR-Sale-Santacruz-West-in-Mumbai&id=4d423632343339313839', 'floors': '4', 'price': 13000000, 'descrip
tion': 'This magnificent 2 BHK Flat is available for sale in Santacruz West, Mumbai. Located in the Vivek Apartments township, the flat enjoys access to the prime spots in the city.  This flat for resale is a choice property. This ready
to move property in Santacruz West is readily available within an affordable cost of  INR 1.30 Cr. You will find it unfurnished. The flat is in close proximity to prominent landmarks like opp mercedes benz shw room.', 'id': '62439189', '
bath': '2', 'beds': '2', 'city': 'Mumbai'}
2022-12-31 13:45:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.magicbricks.com/mbsrp/propertySearch.html?editSearch=Y&category=S&propertyType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&city=4320&page=29&groupstart=870&offset=0&m
axOffset=5&sortBy=premiumRecent&postedSince=-1&pType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&isNRI=Y&multiLang=en>
{'title': '1BHK Multistorey Apartment for Resale in Malad West', 'url': '1-BHK-600-Sq-ft-Multistorey-Apartment-FOR-Sale-Malad-West-in-Mumbai&id=4d423632343339323137', 'floors': 'Ground', 'price': 5000000, 'description': 'Malad West, Mumb
ai has an appealing 1 BHK flat for sale with various amenities. This flat for resale is a choice property. This ready to move flat in Malad West can be taken at a very economical pricing of INR 50 Lac. The apartment is semi-furnished.',
'id': '62439217', 'bath': '2', 'beds': '1', 'city': 'Mumbai'}
2022-12-31 13:45:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.magicbricks.com/mbsrp/propertySearch.html?editSearch=Y&category=S&propertyType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&city=4320&page=29&groupstart=870&offset=0&m
axOffset=5&sortBy=premiumRecent&postedSince=-1&pType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&isNRI=Y&multiLang=en>
{'title': '2BHK Multistorey Apartment for Resale in Mira Road', 'url': '2-BHK-850-Sq-ft-Multistorey-Apartment-FOR-Sale-Mira-Road-in-Mumbai&id=4d423136343934343139', 'floors': None, 'price': 21000000, 'description': "2 BHK flat available
for sale in Mumbai in the prime location of Mira Road. This flat for resale is a choice property. This ready to move flat in Mira Road comes at an affordable price of INR 2.10 Cr. This flat is available for possession on May '15. The fla
t is semi-furnished and is suitable for any family size. icici prudential life insurance are some of the well-known landmarks in this locality.", 'id': '16494419', 'bath': '2', 'beds': '2', 'city': 'Mumbai'}
2022-12-31 13:45:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.magicbricks.com/mbsrp/propertySearch.html?editSearch=Y&category=S&propertyType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&city=4320&page=29&groupstart=870&offset=0&m
axOffset=5&sortBy=premiumRecent&postedSince=-1&pType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&isNRI=Y&multiLang=en>
{'title': '2BHK Multistorey Apartment for Resale in ', 'url': '2-BHK-1150-Sq-ft-Multistorey-Apartment-FOR-Sale-in-Mumbai&id=4d423630303835313537', 'floors': '6', 'price': 35000000, 'description': 'Creatively planned and constructed is a
2 BHK flat for sale in palm house matunga, Mumbai. This is a desirable apartment for resale. This ready to move flat is offered at an economical price of INR 3.50 Cr. This unfurnished flat is strategically designed with all the amenities
 to enhance the living experience.', 'id': '60085157', 'bath': '2', 'beds': '2', 'city': 'Mumbai'}
2022-12-31 13:45:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.magicbricks.com/mbsrp/propertySearch.html?editSearch=Y&category=S&propertyType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&city=4320&page=29&groupstart=870&offset=0&m
axOffset=5&sortBy=premiumRecent&postedSince=-1&pType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&isNRI=Y&multiLang=en>
{'title': '2BHK Multistorey Apartment for New Property in 10 Central Avenue at Santacruz West', 'url': '2-BHK-650-Sq-ft-Multistorey-Apartment-FOR-Sale-Santacruz-West-in-Mumbai&id=4d423236333630373037', 'floors': '5', 'price': 41100000, '
description': 'Carefully laid out in the prime location of Santacruz West in Mumbai, this spacious 2 BHK flat on sale is a meticulously planned project. This flat is placed in a marvellous location within the 10 Central Avenue complex. T
his flat for sale is a choice property. This ready to move flat is offered at an economical price of INR 4.11 Cr. The flat is uniquely designed to enhance the living style. It is semi-furnished, studded with all the basic facilities. Sig
nificant landmarks in its proximity are opp. rose manor international school & karnataka bank,near jain temple ,podar school walking distance.', 'id': '26360707', 'bath': '2', 'beds': '2', 'city': 'Mumbai'}
2022-12-31 13:45:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.magicbricks.com/mbsrp/propertySearch.html?editSearch=Y&category=S&propertyType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&city=4320&page=29&groupstart=870&offset=0&m
axOffset=5&sortBy=premiumRecent&postedSince=-1&pType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&isNRI=Y&multiLang=en>
{'title': '1BHK Multistorey Apartment for Resale in Matunga West', 'url': '1-BHK-450-Sq-ft-Multistorey-Apartment-FOR-Sale-Matunga-West-in-Mumbai&id=4d423632393633373733', 'floors': '1', 'price': 15000000, 'description': 'Matunga West, Mu
mbai has an attractive 1 BHK Flat for sale. This flat all equipped with required facilities, is up for resale. This ready to move flat in Matunga West is available for a reasonable price of INR 1.50 Cr. This immaculate flat boasts of com
ing in furnished form which takes the entire deal to the next level.', 'id': '62963773', 'bath': '1', 'beds': '1', 'city': 'Mumbai'}
2022-12-31 13:45:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.magicbricks.com/mbsrp/propertySearch.html?editSearch=Y&category=S&propertyType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&city=4320&page=29&groupstart=870&offset=0&m
axOffset=5&sortBy=premiumRecent&postedSince=-1&pType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&isNRI=Y&multiLang=en>
{'title': '1BHK Multistorey Apartment for Resale in Shiv Prerna at Linking Road', 'url': '1-BHK-400-Sq-ft-Multistorey-Apartment-FOR-Sale-Linking-Road-in-Mumbai&id=4d423634333331333035', 'floors': '1', 'price': 7800000, 'description': 'Th
is ready to move-in 1 BHK flat is available for sale at the premium Linking Road in Mumbai. Situated in the excellent Shiv Prerna township. The flat enjoys a prime location. Your hunt for the perfect apartment for resale comes to an end
here. This ready to move flat in Linking Road can be taken at a very economical pricing of INR 78 Lac. The flat is sold in semi-furnished condition. this is semi furnished flat in asalpha. 1 bhk flat on 1st floor with 300 sq feet. flat i
s well maintained with fall sealing, lavish hall, bedroom. provision for ac in bedroom. wardrobe is created which is specious to keep the things and use. very good locality to leave. connectivity wise 5 min walking from asalpha metro sta
tion. 1 min walking from linkroad. 3 km from ghatkopar station. are a few nearby landmarks.', 'id': '64331305', 'bath': '1', 'beds': '1', 'city': 'Mumbai'}
2022-12-31 13:45:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.magicbricks.com/mbsrp/propertySearch.html?editSearch=Y&category=S&propertyType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&city=4320&page=29&groupstart=870&offset=0&m
axOffset=5&sortBy=premiumRecent&postedSince=-1&pType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&isNRI=Y&multiLang=en>
{'title': '2BHK Multistorey Apartment for Resale in Malad', 'url': '2-BHK-1200-Sq-ft-Multistorey-Apartment-FOR-Sale-Malad-in-Mumbai&id=4d423630303835353133', 'floors': 'Upper Basement', 'price': 10000000, 'description': 'Malad, Mumbai ha
s an attractive 2 BHK Flat for sale. Your hunt for the perfect apartment for resale comes to an end here. This ready to move property in Malad is readily available within an affordable cost of  INR 1 Cr. The flat is available in semi-fur
nished condition.', 'id': '60085513', 'bath': '2', 'beds': '2', 'city': 'Mumbai'}
2022-12-31 13:45:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.magicbricks.com/mbsrp/propertySearch.html?editSearch=Y&category=S&propertyType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&city=4320&page=29&groupstart=870&offset=0&m
axOffset=5&sortBy=premiumRecent&postedSince=-1&pType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&isNRI=Y&multiLang=en>
{'title': '2BHK Multistorey Apartment for Resale in Powai Vihar Complex at Powai', 'url': '2-BHK-1100-Sq-ft-Multistorey-Apartment-FOR-Sale-Powai-in-Mumbai&id=4d423435363930303139', 'floors': '11', 'price': 21000000, 'description': "This
ready to move-in 2 BHK flat is available for sale at the premium Powai in Mumbai. The property is ideally located in a strategic location in Powai Vihar Complex township. This premium flat is available for resale at an unbelievable price
, so, grab it before it's gone! This ready to move flat located in Powai is available for purchase at a fair price of INR 2.10 Cr. It is unfurnished to accommodate your needs. Some nearby landmarks are lake homes.", 'id': '45690019', 'ba
th': '2', 'beds': '2', 'city': 'Mumbai'}
2022-12-31 13:45:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.magicbricks.com/mbsrp/propertySearch.html?editSearch=Y&category=S&propertyType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&city=4320&page=29&groupstart=870&offset=0&m
axOffset=5&sortBy=premiumRecent&postedSince=-1&pType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&isNRI=Y&multiLang=en>
{'title': '2BHK Multistorey Apartment for Resale in ', 'url': '2-BHK-790-Sq-ft-Multistorey-Apartment-FOR-Sale-in-Mumbai&id=4d423632323038363631', 'floors': '1', 'price': 28500000, 'description': 'This lovely 2 BHK Flat in Blossom apt,  o
pp vishal Hall,  M.V.Road, Andheri east, Mumbai is up for sale. This apartment is a property of choice for resale. This apartment ready to move in the Blossom apt,  opp vishal Hall,  M.V.Road, Andheri east is available for an attractive
price of\xa0INR 2.85 Cr. This contemporary apartment is furnished.', 'id': '62208661', 'bath': '2', 'beds': '2', 'city': 'Mumbai'}
2022-12-31 13:45:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.magicbricks.com/mbsrp/propertySearch.html?editSearch=Y&category=S&propertyType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&city=4320&page=29&groupstart=870&offset=0&m
axOffset=5&sortBy=premiumRecent&postedSince=-1&pType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&isNRI=Y&multiLang=en>
{'title': '1BHK Multistorey Apartment for Resale in Borivali East', 'url': '1-BHK-269-Sq-ft-Multistorey-Apartment-FOR-Sale-Borivali-East-in-Mumbai&id=4d423631313138333335', 'floors': '20', 'price': 7000000, 'description': 'Borivali East,
 Mumbai has an attractive 1 BHK Flat for sale. This apartment is a property of choice for resale. Available at a reasonable selling price of INR 70 Lac, this ready to move apartment in Borivali East is a great buy. This immaculate flat b
oasts of coming in unfurnished form which takes the entire deal to the next level.', 'id': '61118335', 'bath': '1', 'beds': '1', 'city': 'Mumbai'}
2022-12-31 13:45:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.magicbricks.com/mbsrp/propertySearch.html?editSearch=Y&category=S&propertyType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&city=4320&page=29&groupstart=870&offset=0&m
axOffset=5&sortBy=premiumRecent&postedSince=-1&pType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&isNRI=Y&multiLang=en>
{'title': '2BHK Multistorey Apartment in ', 'url': '2-BHK-500-Sq-ft-Multistorey-Apartment-FOR-Sale-in-Mumbai&id=4d423634383039303939', 'floors': '7', 'price': 11500000, 'description': 'This gorgeous 2 BHK Flat is available for sale in 70
2 /703 Shivshakti coop hsg soc ltd,  Shradhanand Road vile parle east behind Ackruti Erica Vile Parle East Mumbai 57, Mumbai. This ready to move flat located in 702 /703 Shivshakti coop hsg soc ltd,  Shradhanand Road vile parle east behi
nd Ackruti Erica Vile Parle East Mumbai 57 is available for purchase at a fair price of INR 1.15 Cr. This furnished flat is strategically designed with all the amenities to enhance the living experience.', 'id': '64809099', 'bath': '2',
'beds': '2', 'city': 'Mumbai'}
2022-12-31 13:45:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.magicbricks.com/mbsrp/propertySearch.html?editSearch=Y&category=S&propertyType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&city=4320&page=29&groupstart=870&offset=0&m
axOffset=5&sortBy=premiumRecent&postedSince=-1&pType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&isNRI=Y&multiLang=en>
{'title': '2BHK Multistorey Apartment for Resale in Kandivali West', 'url': '2-BHK-850-Sq-ft-Multistorey-Apartment-FOR-Sale-Kandivali-West-in-Mumbai&id=4d423435363931333639', 'floors': '7', 'price': 6500000, 'description': 'Kandivali Wes
t, Mumbai has an appealing 2 BHK flat for sale with various amenities. Your hunt for the perfect apartment for resale comes to an end here. This ready to move flat in Kandivali West comes at an affordable price of INR 65 Lac. This premiu
m unfurnished flat spells quality and comfort at a competitive price. Some neighbouring landmarks are near vodafone gallery.', 'id': '45691369', 'bath': '2', 'beds': '2', 'city': 'Mumbai'}
2022-12-31 13:45:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.magicbricks.com/mbsrp/propertySearch.html?editSearch=Y&category=S&propertyType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&city=4320&page=29&groupstart=870&offset=0&m
axOffset=5&sortBy=premiumRecent&postedSince=-1&pType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&isNRI=Y&multiLang=en>
{'title': '3BHK Multistorey Apartment for Resale in Bhandup West', 'url': '3-BHK-1210-Sq-ft-Multistorey-Apartment-FOR-Sale-Bhandup-West-in-Mumbai&id=4d423236333735323435', 'floors': '15', 'price': 25000000, 'description': 'This ready to
move-in 3 BHK flat is available for sale at the premium Bhandup West in Mumbai. This is one of the best properties available for resale. This ready to move flat in Bhandup West can be availed at a reasonable price of INR 2.50 Cr. It is f
urnished to accommodate your needs.', 'id': '26375245', 'bath': '3', 'beds': '3', 'city': 'Mumbai'}
2022-12-31 13:45:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.magicbricks.com/mbsrp/propertySearch.html?editSearch=Y&category=S&propertyType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&city=4320&page=29&groupstart=870&offset=0&m
axOffset=5&sortBy=premiumRecent&postedSince=-1&pType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&isNRI=Y&multiLang=en>
{'title': '1BHK Multistorey Apartment for Resale in Ghatkopar', 'url': '1-BHK-390-Sq-ft-Multistorey-Apartment-FOR-Sale-Ghatkopar-in-Mumbai&id=4d423634333331333733', 'floors': '2', 'price': 7000000, 'description': 'This attractive 1 BHK a
partment can be found for sale in Ghatkopar, Mumbai. This flat is available as a resale property. The ready to move flat in Ghatkopar is all ready for sale at a low-priced budget of INR 70 Lac. The flat is unfurnished and is suitable for
 any family size.', 'id': '64331373', 'bath': '1', 'beds': '1', 'city': 'Mumbai'}
2022-12-31 13:45:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.magicbricks.com/mbsrp/propertySearch.html?editSearch=Y&category=S&propertyType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&city=4320&page=29&groupstart=870&offset=0&m
axOffset=5&sortBy=premiumRecent&postedSince=-1&pType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&isNRI=Y&multiLang=en>
{'title': ' Multistorey Apartment for Resale in Mulund East', 'url': '300-Sq-ft-Multistorey-Apartment-FOR-Sale-Mulund-East-in-Mumbai&id=4d423632323038383839', 'floors': None, 'price': 6300000, 'description': 'Your search ends here, becau
se this flat for resale is among the best bargains in town.', 'id': '62208889', 'bath': None, 'beds': None, 'city': 'Mumbai'}
2022-12-31 13:45:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.magicbricks.com/mbsrp/propertySearch.html?editSearch=Y&category=S&propertyType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&city=4320&page=29&groupstart=870&offset=0&m
axOffset=5&sortBy=premiumRecent&postedSince=-1&pType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&isNRI=Y&multiLang=en>
{'title': '1BHK Multistorey Apartment for Resale in Vinay Unique Homes at Virar', 'url': '1-BHK-645-Sq-ft-Multistorey-Apartment-FOR-Sale-Virar-in-Mumbai&id=4d423537333633313231', 'floors': '4', 'price': 3300000, 'description': "Up for im
mediate sale is a 1 BHK apartment in Virar, Mumbai. Don't miss this bargain flat for sale. It is in a prime location within the Vinay Unique Homes. Your hunt for the perfect apartment for resale comes to an end here. Available at a reaso
nable selling price of INR 33 Lac, this ready to move apartment in Virar is a great buy. The spacious apartment is semi-furnished.", 'id': '57363121', 'bath': '2', 'beds': '1', 'city': 'Mumbai'}
2022-12-31 13:45:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.magicbricks.com/mbsrp/propertySearch.html?editSearch=Y&category=S&propertyType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&city=4320&page=29&groupstart=870&offset=0&m
axOffset=5&sortBy=premiumRecent&postedSince=-1&pType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&isNRI=Y&multiLang=en>
{'title': ' Studio Apartment for Resale in Dadar West', 'url': '400-Sq-ft-Studio-Apartment-FOR-Sale-Dadar-West-in-Mumbai&id=4d423633343934323131', 'floors': '3', 'price': 13000000, 'description': 'Your search ends here, because this flat
 for resale is among the best bargains in town. You can buy this ready to move flat in Dadar West at a reasonable price of INR 1.30 Cr. This premium unfurnished flat spells quality and comfort at a competitive price.', 'id': '63494211',
'bath': '1', 'beds': None, 'city': 'Mumbai'}
2022-12-31 13:45:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.magicbricks.com/mbsrp/propertySearch.html?editSearch=Y&category=S&propertyType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&city=4320&page=29&groupstart=870&offset=0&m
axOffset=5&sortBy=premiumRecent&postedSince=-1&pType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&isNRI=Y&multiLang=en>
{'title': '2BHK Multistorey Apartment for Resale in ', 'url': '2-BHK-1100-Sq-ft-Multistorey-Apartment-FOR-Sale-in-Mumbai&id=4d423630303836363631', 'floors': '10', 'price': 24000000, 'description': 'This magnificent 2 BHK Flat is availabl
e for sale in 7-Bungalows, Mumbai. This is a desirable apartment for resale. The  ready to move flat  in the prime area of 7-Bungalows is available at a reasonable price of INR 2.40 Cr. The flat is uniquely designed to enhance the living
 style. It is furnished, studded with all the basic facilities. Landmarks near the apartment include near versova metro station.', 'id': '60086661', 'bath': '2', 'beds': '2', 'city': 'Mumbai'}
2022-12-31 13:45:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.magicbricks.com/mbsrp/propertySearch.html?editSearch=Y&category=S&propertyType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&city=4320&page=29&groupstart=870&offset=0&m
axOffset=5&sortBy=premiumRecent&postedSince=-1&pType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&isNRI=Y&multiLang=en>
{'title': '3BHK Multistorey Apartment for Resale in Wadala', 'url': '3-BHK-1100-Sq-ft-Multistorey-Apartment-FOR-Sale-Wadala-in-Mumbai&id=4d423630303836383035', 'floors': '14', 'price': 26000000, 'description': 'Discover this immaculate 3
 BHK flat for sale at the pristine Wadala in Mumbai. This apartment is a property of choice for resale. The ready to move flat in Wadala is all ready for sale at a low-priced budget of INR 2.60 Cr. This immaculate flat boasts of coming i
n furnished form which takes the entire deal to the next level.', 'id': '60086805', 'bath': '3', 'beds': '3', 'city': 'Mumbai'}
2022-12-31 13:45:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.magicbricks.com/mbsrp/propertySearch.html?editSearch=Y&category=S&propertyType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&city=4320&page=29&groupstart=870&offset=0&m
axOffset=5&sortBy=premiumRecent&postedSince=-1&pType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&isNRI=Y&multiLang=en>
{'title': '3BHK Multistorey Apartment for Resale in Praful CHS at Kandivali West', 'url': '3-BHK-850-Sq-ft-Multistorey-Apartment-FOR-Sale-Kandivali-West-in-Mumbai&id=4d423532303436303635', 'floors': '5', 'price': 31000000, 'description':
 'This ready to move-in 3 BHK flat is available for sale at the premium Kandivali West in Mumbai. Enjoying a prime location, this property is housed in the Praful Chs society. This flat for resale is the perfect property for you! You can
 buy this ready to move flat in Kandivali West at a reasonable price of INR 3.10 Cr. You will find it furnished.', 'id': '52046065', 'bath': '3', 'beds': '3', 'city': 'Mumbai'}
2022-12-31 13:45:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.magicbricks.com/mbsrp/propertySearch.html?editSearch=Y&category=S&propertyType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&city=4320&page=29&groupstart=870&offset=0&m
axOffset=5&sortBy=premiumRecent&postedSince=-1&pType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&isNRI=Y&multiLang=en>
{'title': ' Studio Apartment for Resale in Mazgaon', 'url': '400-Sq-ft-Studio-Apartment-FOR-Sale-Mazgaon-in-Mumbai&id=4d423634333937343333', 'floors': '2', 'price': 10000000, 'description': 'This is a desirable apartment for resale. This
 apartment ready to move in the Mazgaon is available for an attractive price of\xa0INR 1 Cr. The apartment is semi-furnished.', 'id': '64397433', 'bath': '2', 'beds': None, 'city': 'Mumbai'}
2022-12-31 13:45:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.magicbricks.com/mbsrp/propertySearch.html?editSearch=Y&category=S&propertyType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&city=4320&page=29&groupstart=870&offset=0&m
axOffset=5&sortBy=premiumRecent&postedSince=-1&pType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&isNRI=Y&multiLang=en>
{'title': '1BHK Multistorey Apartment for Resale in Ramdev Park  at Mira Road', 'url': '1-BHK-405-Sq-ft-Multistorey-Apartment-FOR-Sale-Mira-Road-in-Mumbai&id=4d423430333237383735', 'floors': '6', 'price': 6000000, 'description': 'One can
 find this stunning 1 BHK flat for sale in Mira Road, Mumbai. Situated in the excellent Ramdev Park  township. The flat enjoys a prime location. This flat for resale is the perfect property for you! You can buy this ready to move flat in
 Mira Road at a reasonable price of INR 60 Lac. The apartment is unfurnished.', 'id': '40327875', 'bath': '1', 'beds': '1', 'city': 'Mumbai'}
2022-12-31 13:45:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.magicbricks.com/mbsrp/propertySearch.html?editSearch=Y&category=S&propertyType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&city=4320&page=29&groupstart=870&offset=0&m
axOffset=5&sortBy=premiumRecent&postedSince=-1&pType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&isNRI=Y&multiLang=en>
{'title': ' Studio Apartment for Resale in Bhayandar East', 'url': '325-Sq-ft-Studio-Apartment-FOR-Sale-Bhayandar-East-in-Mumbai&id=4d423634303638333933', 'floors': 'Ground', 'price': 3200000, 'description': 'Invest your valuable money i
n this flat that is for resale. This apartment ready to move in the Bhayandar East is available for an attractive price of\xa0INR 32 Lac. This premium unfurnished flat spells quality and comfort at a competitive price.', 'id': '64068393'
, 'bath': '1', 'beds': None, 'city': 'Mumbai'}
2022-12-31 13:45:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.magicbricks.com/mbsrp/propertySearch.html?editSearch=Y&category=S&propertyType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&city=4320&page=29&groupstart=870&offset=0&m
axOffset=5&sortBy=premiumRecent&postedSince=-1&pType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&isNRI=Y&multiLang=en>
{'title': '1BHK Multistorey Apartment for Resale in ', 'url': '1-BHK-390-Sq-ft-Multistorey-Apartment-FOR-Sale-in-Mumbai&id=4d423632393634313131', 'floors': None, 'price': 9250000, 'description': 'This attractive 1 BHK apartment can be fo
und for sale in Shraddhanand Rd, extension , Mumbai. Your hunt for the perfect apartment for resale comes to an end here. This ready to move flat in Shraddhanand Rd, extension  is available for a reasonable price of INR 92.5 Lac. Availab
le in unfurnished state, this flat is a great buy.', 'id': '62964111', 'bath': '1', 'beds': '1', 'city': 'Mumbai'}
2022-12-31 13:45:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.magicbricks.com/mbsrp/propertySearch.html?editSearch=Y&category=S&propertyType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&city=4320&page=29&groupstart=870&offset=0&m
axOffset=5&sortBy=premiumRecent&postedSince=-1&pType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&isNRI=Y&multiLang=en>
{'title': '1BHK Multistorey Apartment for Resale in Dahisar Durga CHS at Dahisar East', 'url': '1-BHK-625-Sq-ft-Multistorey-Apartment-FOR-Sale-Dahisar-East-in-Mumbai&id=4d423633323236343137', 'floors': '6', 'price': 8800000, 'description
': "Up for immediate sale is a 1 BHK apartment in Dahisar East, Mumbai. Don't miss this bargain flat for sale. Located in the Dahisar Durga Chs township, the flat enjoys access to the prime spots in the city.  This is one of the best pro
perties available for resale. Available at a reasonable selling price of INR 88 Lac, this ready to move apartment in Dahisar East is a great buy. The flat is furnished and is suitable for any family size.", 'id': '63226417', 'bath': '2',
 'beds': '1', 'city': 'Mumbai'}
2022-12-31 13:45:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.magicbricks.com/mbsrp/propertySearch.html?editSearch=Y&category=S&propertyType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&city=4320&page=29&groupstart=870&offset=0&m
axOffset=5&sortBy=premiumRecent&postedSince=-1&pType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017&isNRI=Y&multiLang=en>
```

Comment: I think I have to use scrapy-playwright since these are the things I need the program to perform for me: 

1. Scroll and load a lot more entries (around a 1000)
2. Go to each property listing page
3. Interact with a drop down javascript element and scrape that page.

Do you have an idea on how I could do that?

Comment: @AmanRao  `scrapy-playwright` doesn't work on Windows operating syste

Comment: I see. I guess I will have to switch to BeautifulSoup + Selenium.

Comment: @AmanRao  For future reference, you should describe in detail your full objective in your question. When you leave out important details it can lead to people wasting their time coming up with a solution to your problem that doesn't work for you

Comment: I will keep that in mind in the future. Your reply did provide me with insight about using API calls for loading the page. Thank you.